# Listing files in a bare git repository, without git

Tags: linux, git

My company has a server which contains some bare git repos. Git will not be installed there anytime soon.

I want to know if its possible to view at least the file names in these repos without git, but with some more built-in Linux tool

Comment: you mean `ls` ?

Comment: @MickaelB.: in a bare git repository `ls` will only show you the files git uses, not the ones that are checked into the repository.

Comment: Well, to view repository content one needs to unpack some "packed" complex structures located in [bare-repo]/objects/. Thus one definitely needs a specific tool for that. If one doesn't have git (and its internal components), then essentially they need to re-invent git from scratch.

Comment: if you can use `git` binary, then the task can be accomplished with [git ls-tree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree) which works on a bare repository without need to checkout files. `git-ls-tree` is a symlink back to `git` in a modern day git implementation.

Comment: You may try some "pure-something" git implementations like [pure-perl](https://github.com/broquaint/git-pureperl/) or [pure-python](https://github.com/dulwich/dulwich) ones. Thus you can view repository content using only "standard" Linux tools (both perl and python can already pretend that), and "scripts", well, rather complex scripts :-), without need to install some platform dependent binary tools

Comment: If you can bring your own binaries, you could try building (or getting) a statically linked `git` binary and using that.

Comment: I guess I will just statically compile a git binary. Thanks!